# Overriding the logging class in WSGI does not work

Tags: python, logging

I have implemented my own custom Logger for my django site:

```
class SpecialLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name, level=logging.DEBUG):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, name, level)

    def special(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log(self.level, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

In my wsgi file, I have added the lines:

```
import logging
from testbed.utils import SpecialLogger
logging.setLoggerClass(SpecialLogger)
```

In my django views:

```
1  import logging
2  logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')
3  print str(logging.getLoggerClass())
4  print str(logger)
5  print dir(logger)
```

Line #3 prints `testbed.utils.SpecialLogger`

Line #4 prints `<logging.Logger instance at 0x21aadcac>`

And Line #5 (of course) does not show my function `special`

What have I done wrong ? Why is there a discrepancy between lines 3 & 4 ?

Comment: 3 is just printing the class logger is using. 4 is just printing the logger object. What are the contents of 5? Is your question why are these different, or why is special function not available?

Comment: Fundamentally I want to know why the special function is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setLoggerClass function sets the class to be used for all loggers instantiated after the call returns, but any loggers created before the call will still be logging.Logger. You could append a line in your wsgi file to confirm that the correct class is being used, e.g.

```
import logging
from testbed.utils import SpecialLogger
logging.setLoggerClass(SpecialLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger('mylog') # should be a testbed.utils.SpecialLogger
```

If this does not produce the desired effect, some other code (e.g. in `settings.py`) must be instantiating loggers before the above code runs.

Comment: I solved my problem by moving the `setLoggerClass` method a few lines higher in the `myapp.wsgi` file. It works like a charm now.